Dayjs - Set Utc by default
I was using momentjs.
I needed to have the values in utc so I made :
        {
            provide: DateAdapter,
            useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
            deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
        }

Now I've switched to dayjs.
I can't figure out how to do the same thing.
I wanted to make a plugin, but I can't do it:
const customUTC = (option: any, dayjsClass: any, dayjsFactory: any) => {
    const oldDayjs = dayjsFactory;
    dayjsFactory  = (...args: any[]) => {
        // Call the original dayjs constructor with the provided arguments
        const instance = oldDayjs.bind(this)(args)

        // Convert the instance to UTC
        const utcInstance = instance.utc();
        return utcInstance;
    };
};

dayjs.extend(customUTC)

The goal is not to have to do dayjs().uct() systematically, but for it to be basic.
thanks
